# Highcharts comparison with different datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, highcharts

Here is an example of my highcharts:

```js
var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/12puf3';

$.get({
 url: url,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (data) {


    var months      = [];
     datas     = [];
     estimeSapColor   = "#009dc1"; // Bleu - Estimation Fournisseur
   reelGrdfColor   = "#d8662c"; // Orange - Relève Distributeur

   console.log(data.G);


    $.each(data.G, function(index, val) {
      months.push(data.G[index].month + " " + data.G[index].year);
       datas.push(parseInt(data.G[index].consoSimple));
      });
    

    Highcharts.chart('container', {

      chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
     load: function() {
     this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(data.G.length -5 ,data.G.length-1);
     }
    },
   },

      title: {
          text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
      },

      xAxis: {
          categories: months,
          crosshair: true
      },

      yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          min: 5,
          title: {
              text: 'Number of fruits'
          }
      },

      tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
              return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                  this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                  'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
          }
      },

      plotOptions: {
          column: {
              pointPadding: 0.2,
              borderWidth: 0,
              dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                         return this.y > 30 ? this.y : null;
      }
                    }     
          },
    series: {
     formatter: function() {
                         console.log(this.y < 0);
      },
        minPointLength: 5 // Largeur de la colonne
    }
      },


      series: [{
          name: 'Estimation Fournisseur',
          data: datas,
          color: estimeSapColor,
          stack: 'male'
      }]
  });

  
 }
})
.done(function() {
 console.log("success");
 $('.highcharts-button').hide();
 $('.highcharts-axis-title').hide();
})
.fail(function() {
 console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
 console.log("complete");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

You can notice that the first element is May 2013 and the last is may 2014.

Is there a way, a condition, a function, to take the column of may 2014 to put it next to may 2013, without adding a series object?

EDIT:

It should look like this: [image]

Comment: What do you mean by putting it next to may 2013? Should it be in the same category or you want to change the order of the columns - if so you need to change the order of data, so the last column will be the second item.

Comment: Thank you your reply. Litterally, I would like to have the graphic on my post (just edited rigth now). I mean, I would like to have a kind of condition which says "if in May exists in 2013 and 2014, so put them together".

Comment: You need to do grouping by months on your own - Highcharts only visualises data. For each point you can define x value, e.g. [0, 6388], [0, 11146]. Both points will be placed in the category 0, but if you use the same series they will overlap, so you need to position them on your own [-0.2, ...], [0.2, ...] - if you would use two series, positioning would be done automatically, so maybe you should consider use another series anyway - https://jsfiddle.net/jm37tuhs/